# What is the relationship between http connection and request

Tags: nginx, http

I am configuring my `nginx`, and I have found two modules: [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) and [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)
one is for limiting connection per defined key, and one for limiting request.

My question is, what is the relationship (and difference) between
a http connection and a request?
It seems that multi request and use one common http connection, what's the principle under this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HTTP Persistent Connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection):

> HTTP persistent connection, also called HTTP keep-alive, or HTTP
>   connection reuse, is the idea of using a single TCP connection to send
>   and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses, as opposed to opening a
>   new connection for every single request/response pair. The newer
>   HTTP/2 protocol uses the same idea and takes it further to allow
>   multiple concurrent requests/responses to be multiplexed over a single
>   connection.

Comment: So I made a mistake in my question, it is `tcp connection`, rather than `http connection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As connection can be kept alive. I am wondering when while the established connection destroy? I am guessing is there a setting in nginx or linux  like **max_establish_connection** or sth like that, and when established connection count is beyond that some connections are destroyed?  Or, there is just a simple setting like **connection_survival_time**? Which is corret?